# How to pass onclick variable to mysql query in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm getting text value from an `onclick` event. I have saved the data in (`var id`) in using jQuery. In the variable data will check the database and if it is matching it will display all the records.

My html code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6  test" data-idtest="Diabetes">
                    <a href="" class="box_cat_home">
                        <i class="icon-info-4"></i>
                        <img src="assets/img/icon_cat_3.svg" width="60" height="60" alt="">
                        <h3>Diabetes</h3>
                        <ul class="clearfix">
                            <li><strong>124</strong>Doctors</li>
                            <!-- <li><strong>60</strong>Clinics</li> -->
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

My jquery code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.test').click(function (){
        var id = $(this).data('idtest') ; 
        //alert(id);
$.ajax({
     url : "getting.php",
     type: 'POST',
     data    : {id:id },
      }).done(function(response) {
    });
  })
});
</script>
```

How can I achieve this?

Here my php code:

```
<?php
echo "ejejejej";
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = 'mysql';
$dbName = 'fre';

$id =$id;
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

      $men ="select * from tbl_users where doctor_speciality = $id";
      $men_result=$db->query($men);
      $projects=array();
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($men_result)){ 
      $projects[] = $row;

    }


?>
```

please how can i achive this?

Comment: You can use an AJAX request.

Comment: Have you wrote any PHP? Where is it? Is something not working? What's the error? Is your error reporting enabled in PHP? Have you checked your error logs? Have you consulted the console? Did it show any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$.ajax` in jquery library

check [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for reference.

Basic example:

```
$.ajax({
     url : "your_server_url",
     type: 'POST',
     data    : {id:id },
      }).done(function(response) {
            //when request is success , done function is call so you should write anything or leave it empty  
   });
```

replace your_server_url with your server url that call php script which contain mysql query for save id

Comment: Hi Sally Akl, i tried this but from getting.php file also not printing my ajax code : <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('.test').click(function (){
  var id = $(this).data('idtest') ; 
  //alert(id);
$.ajax({
     url : "getting.php",
     type: 'POST',
     data    : {id:id },
      }).done(function(response) {
    });
  })
});
</script>

Comment: first check  url (getting.php) is in correct path and in your getting.php use <?php  echo $_POST["id"] ?>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax.

You send the ID to a controller (in case you are using laravel or any other MVC frameworks) 
or just post it to a PHP file. You select all the needed values from using php and return it as a JSON. ex:

And then you loop through it in jQuery and display it as needed.

```
$.post( "/php/getRecordsById.php", { id: yourSelectedId }, function( data ) {

 //Do Something with recieved data here

}, "JSON");
```

Returning JSON data from php:

```
echo json_encode($yourSelectedData);
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this code :<script>
 $(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".test").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('idtest') ; 
    $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "getting.php",
     success: function(msg){
       
     }
    })
  })
});
</script> it's not working

Comment: @rajkumar Can you explain what is not working for you?